# BillingAPI and message transport

Tags: guidewire

When you cancel a policy in policy center does it update the cancellation status in billing center through BillingAPI? I’m assuming there is a message passed to billing center but I’m not totally sure.

I’m wondering if this is an out of the box functionality or an integration needs to be set up to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have enabled BCBillingSystemPlugin in IBillingSystemPlugin.gwp; by default it's addressing StandAloneBillingSystemPlugin.